# Android Service ("startService & stopService") and Play/Stop Button in One

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-button

I am developing an Android app and I need to make one button which will be a Play/Stop button for Android Service playing and stopping.

- Play button is for `startActivity();`
- Stop button is for `stopActivity();`

How do I make this?

Comment: should have tried first , its a very basic knowledge thing , apply the flag value thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare a flag variable and declare body of onclick() based on flag value like this.

```
public class ServiceActivity extends Activity {
    Button play;
    int button_status=1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(button_status == 1)//play the service
                {
                button_status=0;
                Intent i=new Intent(ServiceActivity.this,Playing.class);
                startService(i);
                }
                else//stop the service
                {
                button_status=1;
                Intent i=new Intent(ServiceActivity.this,Playing.class);
                stopService(i); 
                } 
        });

    }  
}
```

or you can use [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) for your purose.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a boolean to remember if it's on or off and toggle it

```
boolean isOn = false;

public void startStopButton() {
    if(isOn) {
        stopActivity();
        isOn = false;
    } else {
        startActivity();
        isOn = true;
    }
}
```

Now whenever your button is pressed, you can call this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isStop = false;

public void startorStop() {
    if(isStop) {
      // play  it
    } else {
      //stop it  
    }
isStop = !isStop;
}
```